Is there an efficient algorithm for finding the solutions of this exponential equation?
Consider the exponential equation:
$3^i=2^j+1$ where $i, j$ are positive integers.
Is there a pattern using which we can solve for all solutions of this equation efficiently rather than trying $i,j$ one at a time manually?
What we mean by efficiently here is finding the 'next solution' easily, rather than reaching it by incrementing $i$ repeatedly till we reach it.

Such equations are usually very difficult to solve. We can however here use a powerful theorem , namely that the only consecutive perfect powers are $8$ and $9$. This particular equation can surely easier be completely solved , but I am not firm with those methods.
